# Iframe not showing S3 stored PDF

Tags: c#, jquery, amazon-s3, razor, model-view-controller

I have an application which I am building using EF and C# with using Amazon S3 as the file server. What I do is that I upload some PDF's to S3 and store it's URL in my database and then show it in the application. I pass the model using a session to the view and then use `For Each` to iterate through the URL's and for each URL, create a new `iframe` just like below:

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var tempimg in (List<TempImage>)Session["TempImages"])
{
    <fieldset class="invoiceFieldsets" data-step="@i" id="FieldSet_@i" hidden>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="fixed-actions invoiceContainer">
                    <div class="card text-center" id="Picture_@i" style="width:450px;height:500px;background-color:ghostwhite;border:none">
                        @*<div class="card-header">
                                Profit and Loss
                            </div>*@
                        <input type="hidden" id="ImagePath_@i" runat="server" value="@tempimg.ImagePath" hidden />
                        <div class="card-body" display="inline-block" id="imagepreview_@i" style="background-image:url(@tempimg.ImagePath)" hidden>
                            <iframe id="pdfviewer_@i" src="@tempimg.ImagePath" style="width:500px; height:500px;" sandbox="allow-same-origin" hidden></iframe>

                            @*<embed width="500" height="500" name="plugin" id="pdfviewer_@i" src="@tempimg.ImagePath" type="application/pdf">*@

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Based on the value (i.e if the returned URL contains .pdf), I hide or unhide the `iframe`:

```
var imgtype = $("#ImagePath_"+current).val();
if (imgtype.indexOf(".pdf") >= 0) {
    $("#pdfviewer_"+current).prop('hidden', false);
    $("#pdfviewer_"+current).attr('src', imgtype);
}
else {
    $("#imagepreview_"+current).prop('hidden', false);
}
```

The problem I keep having is that the pictures are shown correctly but the PDF is not showing. I do get a warning from CORBS from google but I have tried even bypassing it and it still does not work. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue . I found out that this part of the code `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` when defining the `iframe` was causing the issue. Once i removed it , it started working. I hope this helps anyone else who is going through the same problem.